# How to determine if a trigger was called via CASCADE?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, cascading-deletes

How can I tell my trigger to continue execution only if this was a cascading operation? Is there a keyword for it?

```
IF condition THEN
  IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' AND operation_is_a_result_of_cascade_delete THEN
    RETURN OLD;
  ELSE
    -- my constraints go here
  END IF;
END IF;
```

I want to impose certain conditions, but only if the `DELETE` is not caused by the `CASCADING` keyword of a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but you can use `pg_trigger_depth()` to find out if your trigger was called through another trigger.

If the result is 1, your trigger was called by a top level statement.

Comment: I will check `pg_trigger_depth()`, thanks. But what is unclear in my question? I would like to improve to make it crystal clear.

Comment: The only part about your question that was clear to me was the "rephrasing". I don't know what "continue transaction" is. I guess it is a question of proper technical terms. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: It works, I forgot to accept the answer, sorry! I set it as a condition for trigger firing - `WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() < 1)`, so the cascade deleting runs without even triggering the function. Thank you!